# OperationalError at /register no such table: class_profile

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am getting this error when creating new users.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

I haven't added anything in my settings.py like `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'class.User'`

My models.py:

```
from pyexpat import model
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.checks.messages import CheckMessage
from django.db import models

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    institution = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

My views.py:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            profile.save()

            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been created! You are now able to log in')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
        profile_form = ProfileForm()
    return render(request, 'class/register.html', {'form': form, 'profile_form': profile_form})
```

Comment: You run makemigrations and migrate on your class app?

Comment: what is the error? error trace?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to do the makemigrations

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
```

then apply migration

```
python3 manage.py migrate
```